# C++ passing objects as function arguments

Tags: c++

This C++ code is an example of passing objects as arguments but it's not working. Can someone point out the problem? The problem comes when I declare the objects in `main`. The error says:

> error expected;.

Here's my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

class time 
{
int hours;
int minutes;
public:
void gettime(int h, int m)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
}
void puttime(void)
{
    cout << hours << " hours and  ";
    cout << minutes << " minutes ";
}
void sum(time, time);
};

void time::sum(time t1, time t2)
{
minutes = t1.minutes + t2.minutes;
hours = minutes / 60;
minutes = minutes % 60;
hours = hours + t1.hours + t2.hours;
}

int main()
{
time t1, t2, t3;
t1.gettime(2, 45);
t2.gettime(3, 30);
t3.sum(t1, t2);
cout << "T1= "; t1.puttime();
cout << "T2= "; t2.puttime();
cout << "T3 = "; t3.puttime();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the name `time` after `using namespace std:`, think about what happens if you want to call the [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function. If you need certain classes or function from the `std` name-space, then pull them in explicitly instead (like e.g. `using std::cout;`) Oh, and this is probably the core issue behind your problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Worse, `time` is originally from C, so it exists in `std::` and at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
time t1, t2, t3;
```

To this:

```
class time t1, t2, t3;
```

Because `time` is probably used by something else on your system.  If that fixes the problem, rename your `class time` to something else that isn't already in use.

Answer (score 1):

There is a entity named time in standard library. Just rename it and [it would work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bee33b0614ed23b). Not using `using namespace std;` will not help, as `time` is defined in global namespavce too as per C compatibility